# Assigning a member to a category on join command with discord. Py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm pretty new to Python and discord.py

My plan is to create a Guild server for a game and every guild has its own category.

My question is: Is there a way to assign a user who joins the discord server over command with permissions in a specific category? I know I could do it with roles but you can create more categories than roles.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What permissions should the person have?

Comment: For example. They want to join the Guild Fairplay. They should just see this category and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. You can work with Permissions. Because of Discord's magical Sync Function we can set the Permissions for the Category and they will be automatically applied to other channels in this Category with Sync on.
Search in this area, [You should find it in this category of the Discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.category) :D

Comment: I knew about this one. I mean they should get only the permissions in one category with a command. Right know I have to manually give them the permissions for the category. I know that I could do it with roles but you can create more categorys than roles

Comment: The `overwrites` Param is for perms, pass in a dict